# Is there any event get triggered whenever we change the month in V-CALENDAR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vcalendar, v-calendar.io

I am using v-calendar in my project so when i change the month i am not able to run a function and not able to get changed month.
is there any way to trigger a function when month/year is changed on v-calendar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://vcalendar.io/api/v2.0/datepicker.html#events